# My master’s defense was cancelled with no clear reason. How can I deal with this?

Tags: thesis, masters, germany

I have been doing my master thesis in Germany for the last six months and submitted my thesis this week. I kept in touch with the supervisor while I was writing the thesis and the result was satisfactory to him.

But as I was preparing the slides for my defense today, I suddenly received an email saying that my defense will be cancelled and that a meeting is needed next week. The professor and supervisor want to talk to me regarding the thesis. I asked the reason, but the supervisor did not give a clear reply, and just said that I don't need to prepare anything.

I am pretty sure that my thesis was written and completed independently by me. I am now very anxious about this unexpected situation. How can I approach this situation and prepare for the meeting?

Comment: Answers in comments and follow-ups have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127599/discussion-on-question-by-alex-the-presentation-for-my-master-thesis-was-cancell). Please only post a comment if you expect it to lead to an improvement of the question (see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/7734)). Post answers as answers (even if your answer is that we cannot say what’s going on).

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "I am pretty sure that my thesis was written and completed independently by me". Why "pretty sure"? Why not 100% sure that you wrote it?

Comment: @alex - I hope you've been able to prepare and, more importantly, also relax a bit over the weekend. I'm curious what the outcome is, so I'd like to ask if you can update the question after you've had the meeting.

Comment: So, what happened finally?

Answer (score 10):

The following is obviously an educated guess, so you have to be the judge whether it fits all the information you have:

- Your examiners found something of serious concern in your thesis. This could be potential plagiarism, data manipulation, etc. Otherwise they wouldn’t go through such extreme measures and wouldn’t have cancelled the defence already. The only reason I see for expecting a small issue is that your examiners may not know what they are doing at all (see my third point).
- Your examiners want to see whether you can defend yourself against an accusation properly without preparation. They are fixated on not telling you anything; otherwise your supervisor would not have reacted to your request like this. It is very unlikely that you will get any information out of them before the meeting. (Mind that I don’t condone this strategy here; see the next point.)
- Most importantly: Your examiners are way out of their depths and have no idea how to properly handle such a situation¹. They probably don’t know the default or official method to handle shortcomings or suspected academic misconduct in a thesis (which almost certainly exists) and fail to see things from your point of view, in particular the anxiety they are causing. Even if they want to take you by surprise, they could have just called for a meeting without cancelling the defence or did this at the defence itself – after all, that’s what it’s for. They probably cannot even cancel the defence unilaterally just like this.

Now, what can you do and keep in mind?

- Be able to defend everything you did in your thesis, in particular potential shortcomings. For example, if there are passages where one might want more citations, be able to explain why there are so few. This is not only a good preparation for the meeting per se, but also for the actual defence as well as your confidence.
- Get familiar with the pertaining examination rules. Know which ways **you** have to handle extreme situations and respond to accusations. In particular familiarise yourself with all the steps that need to happen to fail a master’s thesis (it’s usually a lot). You probably have a second professor to examine the thesis who should be able to intervene if things go awry; see whether you can get some general information on them. Finally, by knowing the rules you can also better react to inappropriate procedures being suggested during the meeting and instead insist on the proper procedure.
- As much as your professor’s behaviour sucks for you right now, it probably goes against written or unwritten rules and common sense. This in turn gives you some leverage if the situation escalates further, i.e., end up before a higher committee. In particular, in most fields a proper supervision includes pointing out issues with your thesis **before** you submit (save for misconduct, which may not be obvious).
- You have little to fear if you did not do anything wrong. While this saying sadly doesn’t apply in many areas and is often abused to downplay injustice, it applies to your scenario to a large extent. It is (unfortunately) already very difficult to stick academic misconduct to those who actually committed it – the cases that you get to hear are the extreme ones. If they think you committed misconduct, they have the burden of proof.

---

<sup>¹ This is unfortunately very common. Keep in mind that professors are mostly selected for being researcher-group leaders and not for being bureaucrats. I have seen several professors display astounding ignorance about the procedures and rules of their institutions.</sup>

Comment: ♦ Thank you for your answer. I am very sure there is no  academic misconduct in my thesis. And in my opinion, even if they think there is academic misconduct in my thesis, shouldn't I be asked to give evidence? How can I defend myself if I don't do anything?

Comment: @alex: I expect that they will ask you to provide evidence (defend yourself) during the meeting or after that, depending on whatever the issue is. But remember that you don’t have to provide evidence that you are innocent, they have to provide evidence that you are guilty first (and then you can react to that evidence).

Comment: "Your examiners want to see whether you can defend yourself against an accusation properly without preparation" is an excellent point. Nice catch.

Comment: @Buffy: I agree that this may be what is in their minds. But what they get the way they proceeded is that they'll interview an OP who has been simmering  for several days in  anxiety caused by deliberately keeping them in the dark about the reasons for a procedure that is completely out of the ordinary. Not what I'd call a situation that is conductive to finding truth.

Comment: "Get familiar with the exam rules": this. Also get in contact with someone trustworthy who knows about the specific rules (Vertrauensprofessor? I've also been in places where the Prüfungsamt was very friendly and helpful to students.) Also, this is a situation where I'd bring a friend. The more so, since OP speaks of professor + supervisor in plural.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've seen not only the inexperience @Wrzlprmt writes about but also subtantial amounts of abuse of power, so this is something to be wary of here. Since OP says they did not commit any misconduct, IMHO their best bet is to insist on proper procedure. Including again asking (email = leaving a "paper" trail) the agenda of the meetig and what procedure will follow for the defense. Also write a protocol of the meeting (ask your friend to take notes). *If* this is a situation with abuse of power, accepting the "secretive" terms of the professor puts OP very much into their power.

Comment: ... following the official procedure and keeping a protocol trail can help to counteract this. Let me emphasize that abuse of power doesn't need to be conscious (and I guess it mostly isn't), but the unconscious variety is of course also plain unacceptable.

Comment: 'I have seen several professors display astounding ignorance about the procedures and rules of their institutions.'  That does indeed happen, but to be fair to our fellow academics, I'll point out that, in my experience, it usually results from the people who _were_ selected to be bureaucrats either denying academics access to the documents containing the procedures and rules; or releasing documents and/or verbal statements purporting to contain official procedures and rules, which have not in fact been enacted as such by any valid constitutional process of the institution.

Comment: @DanielHatton: While I have seen some bureaucratic shortcomings as well, I don’t think they will reach that level in Germany – we may be overly bureaucratic, but we also have centuries of experience with it. Either way, that would be an “understandable ignorance”, not an astounding one.

Comment: "such extreme measures and wouldn’t have cancelled the defence already" - what "extreme measures" are we talking about exactly?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Mostly cancelling the defence unilaterally. Also, calling a meeting without saying what is going on.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I see. I can't tell how big a deal this *actually* is at the OP's university (regardless of how big a deal the OP *perceives* it to be). At the university institutes I was in touch with, agreeing on the date of BSc/MSc presentations was usually a rather informal procedure - students would usually pick one of the next free slots in the institute's internal colloquium after handing in the thesis, and rescheduling of those slots could easily occur for various reasons.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Discussing certain issues informally can also be in favor of the OP: A papertrail of something which could be regarded as scientific misconduct (which might have happened unknowingly) could harm the OP more.

Comment: @user151413: I am not exactly sure what you are aiming at, but I understand the asker’s situation such that they did not even informally reveal what was going on. At the very least they should have had opportunity to do so.

Comment: @user151413: while in general an informal way may be favorable for OP, this would come with an opportunity for OP to answer whatever issue is brought up. If the professor/supervisor thinks stating this in email leaves too much of an official trail, a phone call would have been a very obvious solution. But we have instead the refusal to state the purpose/topic/issue of the meeting even when OP asked for it. Plus a  *unilaterally* cancelled defense also without giving a reason. Both are to me red flags pointing to "unfavorable".

Comment: @cbeleites Agreed, the specific circumstances in this case do indeed suggest otherwise. I just wanted to mention that deviating from official protocols and not writing things in emails is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Imagine the OP copying parts of papers in their thesis, potentially due to not being aware that this is not ok (can be a cultural thing, e.g.). Then, it is much better for the OP to tell them informally to get this fixed and resubmit the thesis rather than to take this to the dean of studies. - Not saying this has happened here, just pointing out that keeping things inofficial can be beneficial.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a truly similar situation, but it seems that something has come up. Something that needs to be dealt with seriously. One case I know of was parallel work leading to two very similar doctoral theses, presented simultaneously, answering an important question. The plagiarism question naturally arises. In this case it was worked out satisfactorily to all parties including the wider community.

But it seems to be something that needs to be discussed before people are comfortable going forward. I suspect that the chances are good for a happy outcome, but can't say. That is the reason for the meeting.

I suggest taking a relaxed attitude until you know more.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  What I can't understand is why I can't be told the reasons.  If it is my problem, just tell me where the problem is. But my supervisor just said that he can't give me more info.

Comment: Possibly a misguided attempt to lessen your anxiety, or a way to defer all discussion until the meeting.

Comment: @alex Until next week, just keep in mind that if the guy/woman really wanted to give you a failing grade, there would be no need for a meeting. He/she would write a thesis review with an "insufficient" mark underneath and be done with it. If he/she wants to invest time in meeting you, then you are unlikely to fail.

Comment: @DCTLib  Thank you very much for your help. It really makes me be not so anxious.

Answer (score 2):

You are worried about why they did not explain the matter in the email. Actually, this is for your advantage. If there is a problem and if they explain it in the email, that makes the problem official. If they haven't explained in the email, that means they haven't made up their mind about how to deal with the problem yet. I sense compassion, and opportunity for you to explain your side about the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason to pre-empt these types of situations by *guessing* what people might want; just wait until the meeting and you will find out what is at issue.  In the event that any serious concern is raised, stay calm and do not feel the need to respond contemporaneously; just ask for time to think over any matter raised.